# ConTeXt: help with footnote

Tags: footnotes, context

I can't get the note number (not in the text but under the LaTeX footnoterule) inside the text cage:

MWE

```
\definepapersize[name][width=16.5cm,height=24cm,] %dimensioni pagina
 \setuppapersize[name] % nome pagina
  \setuplayout[grid=yes]
  \usemodule[simplefonts][size=11pt] 
 \setmainfont[my font]
 \setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]
 \setupfootnotedefinition[footnote][location=left]
  \setupnote[footnote][location=page,numbercommand=\hskip1cm] 

   \starttext
    Dummy Text\footnote
    \stoptext
```

Where am I doing wrong?

PS Even using the "default" command at ["Mark Placement"](https://www.contextgarden.net/Footnotes#Mark_Placement) i get:

```
 Undefined control sequence.
\setupnotation
```

Probably this error is due to the fact that I didn't install ConTeXt Mk IV correctly

PS I find the way to skip the footnote mark "inside" with `\setupfootnotes[numbercommand=\hskip3cm,]`. Now the problem is that the number overlap footnote text. So, how can I skip the text of footnote too?

Comment: You need `\footnote{text for footnote}`

Comment: I forgot to put the command in the mwe but in my source code I put it. But it doesn't work anyway

Comment: Not that you ask for it, but I think the [simplefonts module is obsolete](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Simplefonts).

Comment: @mickep I thought `simplefonts` stopped working a long time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the error with `\setupnotation` that you report.  Try updating to the latest beta.

However, I get a spew of errors from `simplefonts`.  That module is deprecated and stopped working long time ago.  It was superseded by the built-in `\definefontfamily` command.  This example works just fine for me:

```
\definepapersize[name][width=16.5cm,height=24cm]
\setuppapersize[name]
\setuplayout[grid=yes]

\definefontfamily[mainfont] [serif] [DejaVu Serif]
\definefontfamily[mainfont] [sans]  [DejaVu Sans]
\definefontfamily[mainfont] [mono]  [DejaVu Sans Mono]
\definefontfamily[mainfont] [math]  [DejaVu Math]
\setupbodyfont[mainfont, 11pt]

\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]
\setupnotation
    [footnote]
    [location=left]
\setupnote
    [footnote]
    [location=page,
     numbercommand=\groupedcommand{\hskip1cm\relax}{}] 

\starttext
Dummy Text\footnote{text for footnote}
\stoptext
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you